# Can you set a default route in Fat-Free Framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

If the Fat-Free Framework (F3) sees that an incoming HTTP request does not match any of the routes defined in your application, is there a way to set a default route for these cases.  For example, to put at the end of all the routes you have defined in the file, a route where any incoming HTTP request that did not match any preceding routes to go there?

Basically, I would like to route any request that doesn't find a match to a specific class/controller.  It seems like this would be something that is possible to do, but I cannot find it anywhere in the F3 docs.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to test it but what if you use a wildcard as last route option?

`$f3->route('GET /*')`

Comment: It's not necessary to register the `/*` route as the last route. The slash is optional for the wildcard route (tested with `3.6`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of registering a default route it's better to register a custom error handler which is able to process `404` and other error codes. This approach allows to reuse the error controller or error function when triggering these errors programmatically; e.g. with `Base->error(404)`.

1. Register the handler with [`ONERROR`](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/quick-reference#ONERROR)
2. Parse [`ERROR`](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/quick-reference#ERROR) with the registered `ONERROR` handler

It's also possible to use the `beforeRoute()` and `afterRoute()` events.

**Example**

```
<?php

/** @var base $f3 */
$f3->set('ONERROR', 'App\Module\Error\Controller\ErrorController->onError');

class ErrorController
{
    public function onError(Base $f3)
    {
        if ($f3->get('ERROR.code') == 404) {
            /**
             * TODO Generate an appropriate HTTP 404 page
             */

            // Handled the `404` error.
            return true;
        }

        // Let Fat-Free Framework's default error handler do the work.
        return false;
    }
}
```